# Equivalent of javascript date.setUTCSeconds(s) in java

Tags: javascript, java, date

probably not the most challenging question, but im fighting with the following date format: 1513428679.1184669

in js works fine:

```
var s = 1513429108.7141557;
var date = new Date(0);
date.setUTCSeconds(s);
-> Sat Dec 16 2017 13:58:28 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

but how do i parse this format in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `double` value is simply seconds since epoch, conversion is easy:

```
double d = 1513429108.7141557;
```

```
// Using old Java Date
Date date = new Date((long) d * 1000);

SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'XX (z)");
fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris"));
System.out.println(fmt.format(date));
```

```
// Using Java 8 Time API with formatter applying time zone
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond((long) d, (long) d * 1000000000 % 1000000000);

DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'xx (z)")
                                         .withZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));
System.out.println(fmt.format(instant));
```

```
// Using Java 8 Time API with timezoned date value
ZonedDateTime dateTime = Instant.ofEpochSecond((long) d, (long) d * 1000000000 % 1000000000)
                                .atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));

DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'xx (z)");
System.out.println(dateTime.format(fmt));
```

I would recommend the third option, using [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

All 3 options prints:

`Sat Dec 16 2017 13:58:28 GMT+0100 (CET)`

Comment: yeah i could have thought of that myself....thx a lot

Answer (score 1):

This will get you close:

```
    double utcSeconds = 1513429108.7141557;
    long longSeconds = (long) utcSeconds;
    long nanos = Math.round((utcSeconds - longSeconds) * 1_000_000_000L);
    Instant inst = Instant.ofEpochSecond(longSeconds, nanos);
    System.out.println(inst);
```

It prints:

```
2017-12-16T12:58:28.714155674Z
```

The printing of the `Instant` implicitly calls `Instant.toString()`, which always produces a string in UTC. So when this says 12:58:28, it agrees with the 13:58:28 you got at GMT+0100 (CET). The last decimals are inaccurate. When comparing to the decimals of the double it seems that the time is 26 nanoseconds before the correct time of 12:58:28.714155700. This comes from the limited precision of a `double`, so it really doesn’t make sense to ask which of the two nanosecond values is more correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this simple code**

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String utcTime = sdf.format(new Date());
Date date = sdf.parse(utcTime);
String utcSecond = date.getSeconds();
```

**What you're looking for is on the utcSecond String...**

Comment: This Answer is outmoded, using troublesome old legacy date-time classes supplanted by the java.time classes. See the [modern Answer posted by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47846487/642706).

Comment: I see, thank you @BasilBourque